# Multiple Search Pagination with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have the following query below which uses the `GET` value of `fname` and `lname` to compare it to a database table:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages
                      WHERE `fname` = '$fname' OR `lname` = '$lname'
                      LIMIT $start, $perpage")
         or die(mysqli_error());
```

When I run the code, it only puts into account the `'lname' = '$lname'` statement.

What I would like it to do is search for either the `fname` or `lname` variables, or both if they both of them are set.

Comment: paste echo "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE `fname` = '$fname' OR `lname` = '$lname' LIMIT $start, $perpage" into your question.

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser wouldnt it return a error since im using php variables?

Comment: im using GET values to filter a table called pages. When I use the logical OR like I put in the beginning, it only processes the `lname` = '$lname', ignoring the `fname` = '$fname'

Comment: can you echo your query and run directly on database ?

Comment: when I use the query that @MahmoudGamal posted, it returns a empty dataset now. Could it be mysql version?

Comment: can you try this $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE (`fname` = '{$fname}' OR `lname` = '{$lname}') LIMIT {$start}, {$perpage}")

Comment: @GBD I tried the statement, it gives me the same result as the initial query I posted. I have two pages, on the first page, the user inputs data into 5 fields: fname, lname, city, state, school. The user is allowed to input in one or more feilds. It then passes it to a second page, where it takes the users inputted feilds, and compares it to the corresponding column information and displays the results with pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query with `LIKE`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages
                        WHERE `fname` LIKE '%$fname%' AND `lname` LIKE '%$lname%'
                        LIMIT $start, $perpage
                    ");
```